# Javascript: FileUri to blob conversion

Tags: javascript, cordova, file-upload, blob, filereader

I want to upload files from local storage. But from local storage I'm getting file url something like `file:///data/user/0/application_package/cache/IMG-199201092.jpg`. I want to convert it to `blob` file or any `array` or `object` of `file` so that it can be send to server via `XMLHttpRequest`. So that on server i can save them.

I'ave tried this code:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var blob_image = reader.readAsDataURL(imageUri);
```

but `blob_image` i couldn't fetch it on server via '$_FILES' as image or something.

I'm getting imageUri from

```
$cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options)
.then(function (results) 
{
   for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
    {
 var image_uri = results[i];
 var fd = new FormData();
 //Take the first selected file                             
 var blobbb = new Blob([new Uint8Array(results[i])], { type: "file" });
 fd.append("file", blobbb  );
 objXhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log( objXhr.responseText );
        }
    };
 objXhr.open("POST", "http://someapi.com/api.php");
 objXhr.send(fd);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, show us the code... You are not showing enough information. How can we troubleshoot the ajax part if you do not show it? Also, what you have is not a dataUrl but a filepath. Also, I'm really wondering how you got to get that full URL as normally you'd only receive the contextual information from an upload form.

Comment: @Salketer , Sure sir i have added code.

Comment: im now trying `var blobbb = new Blob([new Uint8Array(results[i])], { type: "file" });` this code too.. but no success :(

Comment: The problem is that cordovaImagePicker only returns a filepath, not the actual image data... You'll need to use something else to read the file, and upload it. I do not know enough cordova to help on this. But read through this issue, some people show their upload code https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker/issues/26

Comment: Yes it is returning only filepath. I want to read that file :'(